# how to extract words from a string in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

I have a string "this is a string", and I want to iterate over all the words in this string.
Is there a way in which i can easily do this without having to parse it.

Thanks

Comment: The act of iterating over words *is* parsing.  So the answer is no.

Comment: think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 3):

```
void do_something(const std::string& word);

std::for_each( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(is)
             , std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
             , do_something );
```